# Set alpha value to PyQtgraph ImageItem pixel by pixel

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I'm using PyQtgraph to display an image. In particular I'm displaying a bidimensional numpy array (where each point [i,j] is not color data, but just a single value) inside an ImageView, applying a color map to it.

Now I want to add an overlay to it, using as image data another bidimensional numpy array of the same type and size, again mapped to a color map.

I'd like to use different levels of transparency for the overlay, i.e. a different alpha value for each element [i, j] of the second numpy array, computed based on some function (which is not important for the sake of the question), so that the second image will be more or less visibile in different areas.

How could I achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `opacity` option (check the [doc](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graphicsItems/imageitem.html#pyqtgraph.ImageItem.setImage)) in `setImage` method for setting the same alpha for every pixel (`float` number between 0.0 and 1.0).

For a pixel-per-pixel transparency definition, I've not found a valid way to append an `alpha channel` to a grayscale image. The easiest work around I found is to transform the image into a mock RGB and subsequently add the alpha channel:

```
my_fake_rgb_image = np.array([my_grayscale_image]*3 + [alpha_channel]).T
```

**NOTE: The alpha channel value must be designed in the same range as the pixels. If your image is 8-bit (`uint` 0-255), the alpha channel must be a matrix for the same size as the image and with integer values between 0 and 255**

NOTE2: `[x]*3 + [y]` is a shorthand for `[x, x, x, y]`

However, each `ImageItem` (the actual `pyqtgraph` item into `ImageView` that handles and displays the image) can handle one image at a time. What you need, is to implement an extra `ImageItem`s into the same `ViewBox`, such as:

```
# Tailored on your comment
main_image_item = my_image_view.getImageItem()
main_image_item.setImage(my_np_image1)

view_box = my_image_view.getView()
second_image_item = pyqtgraph.ImageItem(my_np_image2, opacity=my_alpha2)
view_box.addImte(second_image_item)
```

NOTE 3: Pay extra-care when using the `ImageView` tools like the histogram, ROI etc., while handling **two** `ImageItem`s instead of one.

A full working example follows, that generates two images made by orthogonal lines. The second image implement a random alpha value pixel-by-pixel:

```
import PySide2
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph import ViewBox, ImageItem, ImageView
import numpy as np


def generate_images():
    from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
    im1 = Image.new('L', (128, 128))
    im2 = Image.new('L', (128, 128))

    draw1 = ImageDraw.Draw(im1)
    draw1.line([0, 0, 128, 128], fill='white', width=10)

    draw2 = ImageDraw.Draw(im2)
    draw2.line([0, 128, 128, 0], fill='red', width=10)

    return np.array(im1), np.array(im2)


app = QApplication()
cm = pg.colormap.get('CET-D1')
iw = ImageView()
iw.setColorMap(cm)

main_image_item = iw.getImageItem()

image1, image2 = generate_images()

main_image_item.setImage(image1)

rand_alpha = np.random.random_sample((128, 128)) * 255

fake_rgb_image2 = np.array([image2]*3 + [rand_alpha]).T

overlayed_image_item = pg.ImageItem(fake_rgb_image2)
iw.addItem(overlayed_image_item)

iw.show()

app.exec_()
```

The result:

[image]

### Edit1:

Modified the answer based on your comment

Comment: Using names from your examples, I don't won't to change main_image_item opacity, that will be fully opaque. What I want is to put second_image_item on top of the main one (adding it to the same view), but setting an opacity value for each of its numpy values (e.g. supposing the second image is NxM, I want to set N x M different alpha values for each of them)

Comment: I edited the answer accordingly

Comment: Note: there was an error into the code, if you had already copied the full example. Now it's corrected

Comment: Thanks for your anwer, but I found an easier solution using pyqtgraph directly by using [pyqtgraph.makeARGB](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#pyqtgraph.makeARGB)

Comment: It's me that thanks you. I didn't know about this helper function. However, it's not clear to me how to use this function for the purpose of this topic. Is the alpha channel to be specified into the `lut` argument? Would you edit my answer integrating the proper usage? 
All the rest, I think, is still valid

Comment: By the way, the image data manipulation is just a line of code. Maybe I still prefer my method (I know it sounds egocentric), I found it more crystal clear on how the data is manipulated. By the way, it's just a matter of taste